# Django creates another media folder inside media folder

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm a beginner with Django and that's exactly what it does. I do just as it was in the documentation but anyway maybe something went wrong?

From admin-page I adding\setting-up a product and choosing the 'image', then when I'm saving it creating a thumbnail and trying to save in '/media/uploads/' but instead it's creating another 'media' folder and the image stored in '/media/media/uploads/img.png' when path on site is '/media/uploads/img.png'. Here is the code:

```py
/shop/settings.py:
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # or even 'media/'

/shop/urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

after that's added, then in my Product model I do:

```py
/apps/store/models.py:
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.thumbnail = self.make_thumbnail(self.image)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def make_thumbnail(image, size=(512, 512)):
        if not image:
            return

        img = Image.open(image)
        if img.mode in ('RGBA',):  # converting image to RGB if it's RGBA
            img.load()
            rgb_convert = Image.new('RGB', img.size, 0)
            rgb_convert.paste(img, mask=img.split()[3])
            img = rgb_convert

        img.thumbnail(size)

        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        img.save(thumb_io, 'PNG', quality=80)
        thumb = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)
        return thumb
```

I tried to change 'upload_to' to 'uploads/' and then it stores files in the right direction but path to it on-site also changes to '/uploads/img.png' when it's must be '/media/uploads/img.png'

What's can be wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly how do you render the on-site path? I think the rendering in the *template* is wrong.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem just using <img src="{{ p.thumbnail }}">, but anyway it's creating another folder, its weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`upload_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) is relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT`. So if you want to store it in a directory `uploads` in the `media` directory, you upload this with:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
```

In order to *render* the URL however, you use the [**`.url`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url), so:

```
{% if p.thumbnail %}
    <img src="{{ p.thumbnail.url }}">
{% endif %}
```

The `{% if p.thumbnail %}` is here necessary to check for `NULL`/`None` values.

Comment: as I described, it's doesn't help because now it's looking for an image in 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/img.png' when with these changes it's stored in 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/uploads/img.png'

Comment: @lipal: Stored yes, but you are *rendering* it the wrong way, you should ***not*** use `{{ p.thumbnail }}`, but `{{ p.thumbnail.url }}`. This will run logic to translate the file into a URL path, by prepending the `MEDIA_URL` to it.

Comment: 'Exception Value: The 'thumbnail' attribute has no file associated with it.' when I trying this

Comment: @lipal: likely the thumbnails you stored the *old* way indeed will not work. For these you will need to manually update the database. If you however upload a new image and thest it for *that* object, it should normally work.

Answer (score 2):

it's cause you wrote "upload_to='media/uploads'"..
from your settings django will create media folder and since you wrote "media/uploads" ,uploads is inside the media folder which is inside main media which was declared in settings. So just write

```
class Product(models.Model):
…
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', blank=True, null=True)
```